# Mi antivirus bloquea mi maquina virtual kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, nmap

Tengo una máquina virtual de Kali Linux en la cual estoy realizando un análisis con la herramienta nmap. Sin embargo, el antivirus de mi computadora bloquea el tráfico generado por nmap, lo que me impide obtener los resultados del escaneo. Necesito subir las evidencias de este pentest para una materia de ciberseguridad. ¿Existe alguna manera de solucionar este problema y poder compartir los resultados de mi análisis a pesar de la intervención del antivirus? Agradezco cualquier orientación o solución que puedan proporcionarme. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Has intentado desactivar el antivirus y/o colocar la VM en modo exclusión?

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias no quería deshabilitar el antivirus pero ya quedo con eso